# UPDATE field based on another row filed value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table stored on a SQL Server 2008, that associate a value to a date range.

```
DateFrom      DateTo         Value
2012-01-01    2012-02-01      10
2012-02-02    2012-02-15      15
```

The application that deal with this table, can insert a new range between the existings.
For example, If i insert

```
DateFrom      DateTo         Value
2012-02-07    2012-02-10      12
```

The result must be

```
DateFrom      DateTo         Value
2012-01-01    2012-02-01      10
2012-02-02    2012-02-06      15
2012-02-07    2012-02-10      12
2012-02-11    2012-02-15      15
```

I can do that programmatically from the application, but I wonder if there is some fast SQL statement that make me able to set the data values by referencing other row's field and performing data operation on it.

A MUST requirement is that the date range must represent a time sequence, two range cannot span each other.

Comment: I did not understand the logic. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: I suspect that there are lots of edge cases to consider here - can a new row have exactly equal From/To as an existing row, and replace it entirely? What if it completely covers multiple rows? I assume it can span two existing ranges?

Comment: The date range must represent a time sequence, two range cannot span each other.

Comment: @AngeloDev - what I meant was, for instance, based on your end result (4 rows), is it valid to insert a row with DateFrom = 2012-02-05 and DateTo = 2012-02-08 - I.e. must two "old" rows be shifted to accomodate this new row?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliver in your case, the new row must be inserted into the two old. And the older must be updated in the DateTo filed, and the new on the DateFrom field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar problems in the past, and found that if the range needs to be continuous the best approach is to do away with the End Date of the range, and calculate this as the Next start date. Then if needs be create a view as follows:

```
SELECT  FromDate,
        (   SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, -1, MIN(DateFrom))
            FROM    YourTable b
            WHERE   b.FromDate > a.FromDate
        ) [ToDate],
        Value
FROM    YourTable a
```

This ensures that 2 ranges can never cross, however does not necessarily ensure no work is required upon insert to get the desired result, but it should be more maintainable and have less scope for error than storing both the start and end date.

**ADDENDUM**

Once I had written out all of the below I realised it does not improve maintainability that much to do away with the `DateTo` Field, it still requires a fair amount of code for the validation, but here's how I would do it anyway.

```
DECLARE  @T table (DateFrom DATE, Value INT)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES ('20120101', 10), ('20120202', 15), ('20120207', 12), ('20120211', 15)

DECLARE @NewFrom DATE = '20120209',
        @NewTo DATE = '20120210',
        @NewValue INT = 8

-- SHOW INITIAL VALUES FOR DEMONSTATIVE PURPOSES -- 
SELECT  DateFrom,
        ISNULL((   SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, -1, MIN(DateFrom))
                    FROM    @t b
                    WHERE   b.DateFrom > a.DateFrom
                ), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) [DateTo],
        Value
FROM    @t a
ORDER BY DateFrom

;WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  DateFrom,
            (   SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, -1, MIN(DateFrom))
                FROM    @t b
                WHERE   b.DateFrom > a.DateFrom
            ) [DateTo],
            Value
    FROM    @t a    
), 
MergeCTE AS
(   SELECT  @NewFrom [DateFrom], @NewValue [Value], 'INSERT' [RowAction]
    WHERE   @NewFrom < @NewTo   -- ENSURE A VALID RANGE IS ENTERED
    UNION ALL 
    -- INSERT A ROW WHERE THE NEW DATE TO SLICES AN EXISTING PERIOD
    SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, 1, @NewTo), Value, 'INSERT'
    FROM    CTE
    WHERE   @NewTo BETWEEN DateFrom AND DateTo
    UNION ALL 
    -- DELETE ALL ENTRIES STARTING WITHIN THE DEFINED PERIOD
    SELECT  DateFrom, Value, 'DELETE'
    FROM    CTE
    WHERE   DateFrom BETWEEN @NewFrom AND @NewTo
)
MERGE INTO @t t USING MergeCTE c ON t.DateFrom = c.DateFrom AND t.Value = c.Value
WHEN MATCHED AND RowAction = 'DELETE' THEN DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES (c.DateFrom, c.Value);

SELECT  DateFrom,
        ISNULL((   SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, -1, MIN(DateFrom))
                    FROM    @t b
                    WHERE   b.DateFrom > a.DateFrom
                ), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) [DateTo],
        Value
FROM    @t a
ORDER BY DateFrom
```

Comment: this is a good solution, but I cannot follow your suggestion cause to the database structure.

Comment: I've added an example of how I would maintain the integrity on insert etc with the structure I suggested and realised that it is basically the same approach as when keeping the `DateTo` field so I am not sure there is much advantage to my suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I've written an example based on the example I gave you in a comment, it may do what you want. Since, in general terms, there might be multiple rows to insert/delete, it's best to define them all separately, then use a `MERGE` to perform the overall change.

I've also assumed that it's okay to delete/insert to achieve the splitting - you can't update and produce 2 rows from 1, so you'd always have to do *an* insert, and the symmetry is cleaner if I do both:

```
declare @T table (DateFrom datetime2, DateTo datetime2,Value int)
insert into @T(DateFrom   ,   DateTo    ,     Value) VALUES
('20120101',    '20120201',      10),
('20120202',    '20120206',      15),
('20120207',    '20120210',      12),
('20120211',    '20120215',      15)

select * from @t order by DateFrom

declare @NewFrom datetime2 = '20120205'
declare @NewTo datetime2 = '20120208'
declare @NewValue int = 8

--We need to identify a) rows to delete, b) new sliced rows to create, and c) the new row itself
;With AlteredRows as (
    select @NewFrom as DateFrom,@NewTo as DateTo,@NewValue as Value,1 as toInsert
    union all
    select DateFrom,DATEADD(day,-1,@NewFrom),Value,1 from @t where @NewFrom between DATEADD(day,1,DateFrom) and DateTo
    union all
    select DATEADD(day,1,@NewTo),DateTo,Value,1 from @t where @NewTo between DateFrom and DATEADD(day,-1,DateTo)
    union all
    select DateFrom,DateTo,0,0 from @t where DateTo > @NewFrom and DateFrom < @NewTo
)
merge into @t t using AlteredRows ar on t.DateFrom = ar.DateFrom and t.DateTo = ar.DateTo
when matched and toInsert=0 then delete
when not matched then insert (DateFrom,DateTo,Value) values (ar.DateFrom,ar.DateTo,ar.Value);

select * from @t order by DateFrom
```

It may be possible to re-write the CTE so that it's a single scan of `@t` - but I only think it's worth doing that if performance is critical.

Comment: It doesn't work correctly when the new range covers a saved range(s) entirely. To account for those cases, I changed the conditions for the two "modifying" SELECTs (those with DATEADDs) like this: `@NewFrom BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, DateFrom) AND DateTo` for the one that shifts the range end and `@NewTo BETWEEN DateFrom AND DATEADD(DAY, -1, DateTo)` for the one that shifts the beginning.

Comment: @AndriyM - it was exactly those kind of edge conditions I wished to establish with the OP - what does this query have to support?

Comment: Sorry but I'll +1 your solution as it is, because I liked the entire approach very much.

Comment: Well, yes, but your answer did seem (to me at least) to solve the problem in question, it only wanted a tiny tweak to improve the functionality. And I think, with that change, it actually covers all possible cases.

Comment: @AndriyM - um, no problem... I've never seen someone apologize for +1ing :-)

Comment: @AndriyM - if you want to edit it in, feel free. I'm not prissy about such things.

Comment: Thanks. You may well not be prissy but you do want to be sure that I don't break your solution with my edit. :) I hope you will test it after I'm done. (I did test it too of course, but just in case I missed something...)

Comment: God work guys, but how can I face the a range that cover entirely two rows. Whit that code, if I declare declare NewFrom datetime2 = '20120201' declare NewTo datetime2 = '20120206' the end result fails

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cursor to get each row from the table at a time and aftwerwards do the necessary calculations.

```
If NewDateFrom >= RowDateFrom and NewDateFrom <= RowDateTo ...
```

---

Check [this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/) to see how to make a cursor.